# Freeze while using touchpad

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, nvidia-prime

There is a small [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/1220426/) that affects me. It already solved and fix released, but updated package accessible only for *vivid* and higher.

1. I do not know what I must to do to apply this to *trusty*?
2. Must I do it before or after `nvidia-355` and `nvidia-prime` installation?

Currently I have no drivers installed.

By default, to do this I use following commands:

1. Add repository

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

2. Update package DB

`sudo apt-get update`

3. Install nvidia-prime and nvidia drivers

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime`

P.S.: I'm using Ubuntu Trusty x86-64 with kernel 3.13.0-63-generic.